# Will all google APIs require oauth2, or just client-side?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-oauth

I'm currently using the Google Distance MatriX API on in a server-side application as:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=STARTING_ADDRESS&destinations=DESTINATION_ADDRESS&key=MY_GOOGLE_API_KEY, which returns some JSON which is then consumed on the server.

I received an email from Google saying that they will be switching to OAuth2, but I'm not sure if they were referring to server applications or only client-side applications.

Does anybody know what they're actually doing, and if the above call will stop working eventually?

Comment: To answer the question definitively, we'll need more info. Absent that, yes, if OAuth is added, HTTP calls will need to reflect a user (or service account) identity in the form of an authorization token.

Comment: @DazWilkin: What kind of info?

Comment: What is the content of Google's email? What specifically were you told?

Comment: Don't have the email anymore. I guess I'll just wait and see what happens.